# How can I remove control characters from a string?

Tags: delphi

I have a string which contains some trailing control characters:

```
'ase_Record'#$A#9#9#9'
```

I tried to use `StringReplace` to remove the control characters, but could not make it work. How can I remove these control characters?

Comment: What do you want to remove? The "#$A#9#9#9" sequence?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use [`Trim`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE3/en/System.SysUtils.Trim):

```
MyString := Trim(MyString);
```

From the [documentation](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE3/en/System.SysUtils.Trim):

> Trims leading and trailing spaces and control characters from a string.

Perhaps you only want to trim from the end of the string. In which case use `TrimRight`. And for completeness there is also `TrimLeft` for those times when you only want to trim from the start of the string.

Comment: Agree with @David Heffernan

Comment: There is also `TrimLeft()` and `TrimRight()` functions available.

Comment: @RemyLebeau The last paragraph says precisely that